# How do I set a newly created user account to NOT prompt the user to change their password?

Tags: rhel, users

I created a new user account, but the user is prompted to change their password on first login.  I don't want them to change their password, I want them to use the password they were assigned.  How do I change their account so they aren't prompted to change their password when they log in?

Comment: Please include the exact command (you can change the username and password ;) used to create the user.

Comment: The user account was created by a program, not a standard Linux command. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be default behavior, so you may be doing something at user creation that is causing the prompt to happen. Prompting at next login is usually done by `chage -d0 <userName>`. There are third party PAM modules that may not do this, but that's out of the scope of what I have knowledge about.

You may want to post the specific steps you're going through to create a user.

Comment: Thanks.  I used `chage -d 1000 <username>`.